# Simplifying a Trigonometric Expression with Sum Difference Identity

Tags: trigonometry

I have a formula here involving some trig and I have to simplify it in order to take the partial derivatives for the error calculation.  Unfortunately, trig identities have always been my weakness.

$$n= \frac{\sin(\frac{x+y}{2})}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}$$

The instructions were to expand it out and simplify before taking the derivatives.  It was hinted at that the sum difference identity $\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)$ would be helpful.

I applied the identity and ended up with this:

$$n=\frac{\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{y}{2})+\cos(\frac{x}{2})\sin(\frac{y}{2})}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}$$

I've been staring at this for much longer than I'd like to admit but cannot see how to get it in simpler terms than the original equation.

Comment: When the instruction (or goal) is to "simplify", you should be asking "Why am I simplifying this?  How will it make future computations easier?"  In this case, it seems like you are getting ready to differentiate, so it might be nice to get an expression that doesn't look like a fraction.  Perhaps the next step would be to write $$\frac{\sin(\tfrac{x}{2})\cos(\tfrac{y}{2})+\cos(\tfrac{x}{2})\sin(\tfrac{y}{2})}{\sin(\tfrac{x}{2})} = \cos(\tfrac{y}{2}) + \tan(\tfrac{x}{2}) \sin(\tfrac{y}{2}). $$

Comment: If you break up the numerator, you can see that $\color{blue}{n = \cos(y/2) +\cot(x/2)\sin(y/2)}$. This should be easier to differentiate with respect to $x$, if that was your goal.

Comment: That being said, this seems to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Without further context about what it is that you are actually trying to accomplish, it is going to be hard to give a good answer.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes that makes so much sense now.  However, shouldn't it be cot instead of tan as stated by MinusOne-Twelfth since cos/sin=cot?  I am preparing the equation to have the partial derivative taken of n with respect to x and also the partial derivative of n taken with respect to y.

Comment: @canadaboy25 Indeed.  Pardon the dyslexia.